# How to extract the data from List in rows using plsql

Tags: oracle, plsql

```
SELECT JSON_QUERY(A.RESPONSEXML,
'$.banking_info.ccris_banking_details.outstanding_credit.items[*].subAccount.subAccountItem.subAccountItem1.credit_position.items'
WITH ARRAY WRAPPER)
  FROM RAMCI_RESPONSE A
 WHERE A.APPID = '5004505'
   AND ROWNUM = 1;



 DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(ITEMSDATA);
```

END;

this is the string which i am getting after data extract from above query

```
[["","","2","1","1","1","1","0","0","0","0","0"],["","","0","0","0","1","2","3","2","0","0","0"],["","","0","0","1","2","2","1","1","1","2","0"],["","","0","0","0","1","2","2","2","1","0","0"]]
```

how we can get the data in rows ?

Comment: Thanks Tejash to correct formatting of question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the hierarchy query as follows:

```
SQL> with dataa (d) as
  2  (select '[["","","2","1","1","1","1","0","0","0","0","0"],["","","0","0","0","1","2","3","2","0","0","0"],["","","0","0","1","2","2","1","1","1","2","0"],["","","0","0","0","1","2","2","2","1","0","0"]]' from dual)
  3  -- query starts from here
  4  select '[' || ltrim(ltrim(regexp_substr(d,'[^]]+',1,level) || ']',','),'[') as str
  5  from dataa
  6  connect by level <= regexp_count(d,'\[') - 1;

STR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
["","","2","1","1","1","1","0","0","0","0","0"]
["","","0","0","0","1","2","3","2","0","0","0"]
["","","0","0","1","2","2","1","1","1","2","0"]
["","","0","0","0","1","2","2","2","1","0","0"]

SQL>
```

**-- Update:**

```
SQL> with dataa (d) as
  2  (select '[["","","2","1","1","1","1","0","0","0","0","0"],["","","0","0","0","1","2","3","2","0","0","0"],["","","0","0","1","2","2","1","1","1","2","0"],["","","0","0","0","1","2","2","2","1","0","0"]]' from dual)
  3  -- query starts from
  4  SELECT COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN CNTR > 1 THEN 1 END),0) AS CNTR
  5  FROM
  6  (SELECT T.STR, REGEXP_SUBSTR(T.STR, '[0-9]+',1,COLUMN_VALUE) AS CNTR FROM
  7  (select LTRIM(regexp_substr(d,'[^]]+',1,level),',') as str
  8  from dataa
  9  connect by level <= regexp_count(d,'\[') - 1) T
 10  CROSS JOIN
 11  table(cast(multiset(select level from dual
 12  connect by  level <= length (regexp_replace(t.STR, '[^,]+'))  + 1)
 13  as sys.OdciNumberList)) levels);

      CNTR
----------
        10

SQL>
```

Comment: Want to iterate each element in array of array and want to increase the counter if element is greater then 1

Comment: But that was not the initial question. and I don't understand this - _want to increase the counter if element is greater then 1_

Comment: suppoe i'll start with counter 0 and in 1 array 3 element is 2 then counter will increase by 1 then second array has 2 then counter become 2 that will run end of the array .

Comment: Can we run counter for every rows and show the output like:
1 row -> 1
2 row -> 3
3 row -> 3
4 row -> 3